# Realtime browser refresh on css/html edit

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I watched a screen cast of a designer working on some css with realtime browser refreshes.  The neat thing about the video is that the browser would automatically display any css or html changes in real time, without the need of clicking the refresh button.

I'm using a mac with safari, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via the [Safari Developer Tools](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html) (Develop > Show Web Inspector)

The Develop menu can be enabled via Safari > Preferences > Advanced (tick ‘Show Develop menu in menu bar’).

Please note that this does not edit the actual file but what you see in the browser (AKA what is being rendered).

Comment: From what I can tell, this will allow me to see the source and view the html/css from what has already been written.  I want to have the browser show my changes in real time as I build the pages.

Comment: The previous comment will get you *access* to real-time editing. How to do this is not always obvious. After the web inspector is displayed, make sure 'elements' (top left corner) is selected. Then you can expand the source below and double-click on the attribute or text. This will enter the editing mode. Make the code changes and tap the keyboard enter/return to make these changes visible in real-time.